# Angular4 - Filtering on deep records

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm creating my shop app, i want to use filter to my list of all products in shop. My products table is devided into multiple categories and later Id of products. When i set manually path **/products/apple** it's working and filter my new array of apple items. But i want to implement this to all products. How can i skip that genres column and search deeper?

my service:

```
getAll() {
    return this.db.list('/products/ps4');
  }
```

my AppComponent.ts

```
export class AppComponent implements OnDestroy {
  products: {name: string}[];
  filteredProducts: any[];
  subscription: Subscription;

  today: Date = new Date();

  constructor(
    private auth: AuthService,
    router: Router,
    private userService: UserService,
    private productsService: ProductsService
  ) {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.today = new Date();
    }, 1);

    auth.user$.subscribe(user => {
      if (user) {
        userService.save(user);

        let returnUrl = localStorage.getItem("returnUrl");
        router.navigateByUrl(returnUrl);
      }
    });

    this.subscription = this.productsService
      .getAll()
      .subscribe(products => (this.filteredProducts = this.products = products));
  }

  filter(query: string) {
    this.filteredProducts = (query) ? 
      this.products.filter(p => p.name.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())) : this.products;
    console.log(query);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }


}
```

and my json file:

[image]

```
<input #query (keyup)="filter(query.value)" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
          <ng-container>
            <div *ngFor="let f of filteredProducts">
              {{ f.name }}
            </div>
          </ng-container>
        </div>
```

**EDITED**

```
filter(query: string) {
    this.filteredProducts = (query) ? 
      this.products.map(category => {
        return category[Object.keys(category)[0]]
      }).filter(p => p.name.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())) : this.products;
    console.log(this.filteredProducts);
  }
```

Comment: Are you using firebase? Did you want to filter in the backend? It seems that there would be too much data to download it all and filter it on the client. Here is a link for filtering using angular file: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/querying-lists.md

Comment: yeah it's nice, but i have problem with AngularFireAction with database or database/deprecated. When i remove deprecaded page works but he didn't see snapshotChanges() when i add deprecated i got error; No provider for AngularFireDatabase ;/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, your question about is a little vague about exactly what format you are wanting the end result. The following flattens all products into a single array of root product values, I think this is what you are asking for...

```js
var products = [{
    apple: [{
        category: 'apple',
        name: 'cold apple',
        producer: 'producer1',
        screen: 'screen1'
      },
      {
        category: 'apple',
        name: 'name2',
        producer: 'producer2',
        screen: 'screen2'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    coolers: [{
        category: 'cooler',
        name: 'name3'
      },
      {
        category: 'cooler',
        name: 'name4'
      }
    ]
  }
];

var mapped = products.map(category => {
  return category[Object.keys(category)[0]];
});
var result = [].concat(...mapped); /*<!-- I'm not sure if this is the best implementation (it looks awful).*/
console.log(result);
console.log(result.filter(r => r.name.indexOf("c") > -1 || r.category.indexOf("c") > -1));
```

---

**Edit**

 In response to the comments. You need to filter by both name and category:

```
.filter(p => (p.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) > -1) || (p.category.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) > -1)
```

Comment: You are amazing! That's what i was looking for, to skip that 'apple' and many other categories and map them to one array, many many thanks!!

Comment: Glad I could help @FreeStyle09.. I saw the comments on your question and would agree that the very best approach would be to flatten this on the backend. But also saw your comment regarding the issues you have with this.

Comment: One mistake :/ It searching but i have not completly results, what have i missed? Edited code for you

Comment: yeah i know to flat this on backed but, the problem is i builded structrue to my multi lvl routing and there's no way around :/

Comment: When i write 'c' shows my 2 mac products but i have 2 coolers and don't show them... u know what i did wrong ?

Comment: and when input is empty it shows me all products well

Comment: @FreeStyle09 Probably because you're filtering on name and not category ? I edited my snippet and filtering on name seems to do as expected.

Comment: @FreeStyle09 Potentially you could loop all properties of the item and search for a string match.

Comment: two items has got same category 'coolers' and when i press 'c' shows only one :/

Comment: i've changed to category i didn't mention

Comment: @FreeStyle09 See edit with working example that selects the 2 coolers and the "cold apple" when searching for 'c'.

Comment: That one cooler is still missing :D i don't know what is going on

Comment: @FreeStyle09 You are missing the core part of my original example still `var result = [].concat(...mapped);` <!-- have to flatten before you can filter

Comment: ohh... wait a sec, so sorry for that

Comment: When i try to put mapped to result i got this error :Type 'Observable<any>' is not an array type.

Comment: Ok it works , i missed one letter ... Many thanks to you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Because your JSON in not an array, you cannot directly use `map` on each entry, but you can fake it with `Object.keys` and `reduce`. That way, you can process every product type and apply the filter on each

```
const filteredProducts = Object.keys(products).reduce((result, key) => {
    const product = products[key];
    result[key] = product.filter(p => p.name.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase()));
    return result;
}, {});
```